# Setting the color of an image mask in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have recently used the iOS Artwork Extractor (found here: http://tinyurl.com/mwza859) to find some sample icons while developing my app. I discovered that Apple stores the images like so:

[image]

But in actual fact the icon is shown on the device like so:

[image]

How would I do the same in my application?

Answer (score 1):

Set the tintColor of that UIImageview.

If that doesn't work. Try this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode
```